# How can I convert an integer into an IP address with Lua?

Tags: lua, ip

I have this `2709862549` and want to convert it to the string IP like `149.56.133.161`
Is there any function for this in LUA I couldn't google that info.

Answer (score 0):

Found it already

```
function intToIp(n)
    n = tonumber(n)
    local n1 = math.floor(n / (2^24)) 
    local n2 = math.floor((n - n1*(2^24)) / (2^16))
    local n3 = math.floor((n - n1*(2^24) - n2*(2^16)) / (2^8))
    local n4 = math.floor((n - n1*(2^24) - n2*(2^16) - n3*(2^8)))
    return n4.."."..n3.."."..n2.."."..n1
end
```

Comment: Instead of the "expensive" exponential and division operations you should consider basic - and actually simpler - bitwise operations: `local n1 = bit.band(bit.rshift(n, 24), 255)` and so on (rinse and repeat with 16, 8, and 0 instead of 24).